# Existing posts keep on re-add upon deletion of selected row in jTable

Tags: sql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I try to refresh the data of jTable upon deletion of selected row. Here are my codes to set up table :

```
    private JTable getJTableManageReplies() {
    jTableManageReplies.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTableManageReplies.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        int viewRow = jTableManageReplies.getSelectedRow();
                        // Get the first column data of the selectedrow
                        int replyID = Integer.parseInt(jTableManageReplies.getValueAt(
                                viewRow, 0).toString());

                        eForumRepliesAdmin reply = new eForumRepliesAdmin(replyID);
                        replyID = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure that you want to delete the selected reply? " , "Delete replies", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if(replyID == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        reply.deleteReply();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reply has been deleted successfully.");
                        SetUpJTableManageReplies();
                        }   
                    }
                }
            });
    return jTableManageReplies;
}

    public void SetUpJTableManageReplies() {

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTableManageReplies
            .getModel();
    String[] data = new String[5];
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select forumReplies.reply_ID,forumReplies.reply_topic,forumTopics.topic_title,forumReplies.reply_content,forumReplies.reply_by from forumReplies,forumTopics WHERE forumReplies.reply_topic = forumTopics.topic_id ";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);

    jTableManageReplies.repaint();
    tableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();


    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            data[0] = resultSet.getString("reply_ID");
            data[1] = resultSet.getString("reply_topic");
            data[2] = resultSet.getString("topic_title");
            data[3] = resultSet.getString("reply_content");
            data[4] = resultSet.getString("reply_by");
            tableModel.addRow(data);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

And this is my sql statement :

```
    public boolean deleteReply() {
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "DELETE FROM forumReplies where reply_ID = " + replyID
            + "";
    if (db.updateRequest(sql) == 1)
        success = true;
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

I called the repaint() to update the table data with the newest data in database and it works. I mean the data after deletion of certain row. However, the existing posts will keep on re-add. Then I add the removeAllElement method to remove all the existing posts because my sql statement is select * from table. Then, there is an error message which is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any guides to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post SSCCE? Which means **Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example** And your code is no were near to this. Please remove all the unwanted codes for us and post simple code that shows the problem.

Comment: I edited already. I can use the repaint method to update the table data. However, I want to delete the existing posts because they will keep on adding. But when I call the removeAllElement method, the arrayIndexOutOfBoundException occurs. I even tried the setRowCount(0) method and it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I called the repaint() to update the table data with the newest data
>   in database and it works.

There is no need to call `repaint` method when data is changed. Data change is handled by the `Table Model` ([DefaultTableModel](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) in this case.) And `fireXXXMethods` are required to be called whenever data is changed but you are using `DefaultTableModel` even those are not required. (Since by default it call these methods when ever there is a change.)

I think the problem is in the `valuesChanged(..)` method. You are getting the value at row 0 but not checking whether table has rows or not. So keep a constraint.

```
int viewRow = jTableManageReplies.getSelectedRow();
// Get the first column data of the selectedrow
if(jTableManageReplies.getRowCount() > 0)
    int replyID = Integer.parseInt(jTableManageReplies.getValueAt(viewRow, 0).toString());
```

Comment: Ya it works now! Thanks a lot. So the fireTableDataChanged method serves the purpose of notify the table whenever there is any data changed? Is it correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Any change in data is handled by the _Table Model._ And one more thing **repaint()** is required if there is a change in components that is adding or deleting components. So use it appropriately. Have a great weekend .. :-)

Comment: Use `validate()` when adding or deleting components; use `repaint()` when changing unbound properties. +1 for identifying the need to `repaint()` as a problem to be solved in the model.